# Eclipse: How do I turn on Context Information automatically without pressing cntrl+shift+space

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

I want to achieve the same effect as in Visual studio- when you open a bracket "(" a little pop-up shows and lists the parameters of the function. In eclipse this option is available but after pressing cntrl+shift+space. Is there a way to set this automatically? Thank you.

Comment: Which perspective are you using?

Comment: Ehm debug, but I forgot to mention that I'm using PHP Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the default activation trigger from

```
.
```

to

```
.abcdefghijklinopqrstuvwxyz
```

[image: ContentAssist]